# What happens if we forward request from spring mvc using requestdispatcher.forward() and still return true ?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, interceptor

i have a protected request mapping "/admin" , requests coming to this url pattern has to go through a interceptor, in that i am checking the roles of the user, if the user has "guest" role i am forwarding that request to some role request page, else normal page.

like below

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
if(role == "admin"){
// do nothing
} else 
{
request.getRequestDispatcher("rolerequestpage").forward(
                request, response);
}
return true;
}
```

Now i am getting both role requestpage and admin page in the same response.

Comment: Answering the title question (according to javadoc): "true if the execution chain should proceed with the next interceptor or the handler itself. Else, DispatcherServlet assumes that this interceptor has already dealt with the response itself". If you need something else, you need to explain what's the expected behavior, what you are getting, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RequestDispatcher defines an object that receives requests from the client and sends them to any resource (such as a servlet, HTML file, or JSP file) on the server. The servlet container creates the RequestDispatcher object, which is used as a wrapper around a server resource located at a particular path or given by a particular name.

Actually the RequestDispatcher.forward() and RequestDispatcher.include() are just method calls to the other JSP/servlet.

**The control (flow of program)is indeed returned to the line after this line once it completes. The body of the code after the forward will still be processed and any unhandled exceptions will be thrown to requesting servlet.**

The control is absolutely returned. However, there are some restrictions on what you can do afterwards -- in particular, you can no longer write to the response (it is assumed that the forwarded-to servlet took care of that already), so the only prudent thing to do is "return".

Comment: thanks for the reply, in my case both the error page and admin page are combined and rendering in the browser.